# Difference between MX record and A record with "mail" (mail.example.com)

Tags: domain-name-system

I am trying to set up a mail server on my droplet.

Could I just create domain name `mail.example.com` with A record, and don't create any MX record?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes and No.**

An A record of 'mail.example.com' will receive email for user@mail.example.com

If you want to receive email for example.com on the server at A record `mail.example.com.` then you would need an MX record at example.com of something like `example.com. IN MX 10 mail.example.com.`

If an MX record also exists, that will be use instead of the A record.

**As for the Difference between MX and A record.**

- MX record can list multiple hosts that handle mail for as single domain
- MX records can be A and AAAA records (so IPv4 and IPv6)
- MX records allow for failover (multiple MX records) whereas A records can have multiple IPs, they will not provide failover as Round-Robin A records assume all answers are valid/available.

**Also:**

- What you name the A record does not matter. `mail` does not magically send email to that server.
- You may have issues sending and not being marked as spam without MX, SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records, generally spam filters expect an MX record. [Exim](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_45.html#SEC804) For example

Answer (score 1):

> Could I just create domain name mail.sample.com with A record, and
>   don't create any MX record?

No. An A record is a host record. An A record doesn't tell email servers where to send email, even if the A record is mail.yourdomain.com. You need an MX record to tell email servers where to send email for your domain.

Note that your MX can "point" to any A record. Your mail server A record does not need to be named mail.yourdomain.com.

Comment: This is so well established  as best practice it would be a bad idea to ignore it - especially with all the spam filter assumltions, but your answer is not correct. Section 5.1 of RFC5321 requires fallback if no MX exists for the domain, so an A record (or even a CNAME which resolves to an A record can be used, and will be treated Luke an MX with priority 0).

Comment: Thanks. I'm well aware of the fallback to A record mechanism, and considered adding that to my answer, but I didn't feel like that was really the crux of the question. Could you? Technically, yes. Should you? Probably not. Maybe that's what I should have stated in my answer.

Comment: I actually do think that's relevant - if its a dev server, it may be acceptable under a controlled environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using an `A` record for example.com (not `mail.example.com`). I would not advise this as is not a best practice  especially with all the spam filter assumptions.

(Section 5.1 of RFC5321 requires fallback if no `MX` exists for the domain, so an `A` record (or even a `CNAME` which resolves to an A record can be used, and will be treated like an `MX` with priority 0)

To clarify, if email is going to user@example.com you would need an a record for `example.com`, not `mail.example.com` - thus could technically be an `A` record not an `MX` record.

Comment: (remember that you can not have a `CNAME` record at the apex...)

Answer (score 0):

An MX record's purpose is to tell someone who wants to send you mail where to go to deliver that mail to your domain's MTA. If your domain lacks an MX record, despite having an A record with the name `mail`, some hosts will not know where to send email to, as some are able to fallback to looking for an A record.

Having an MX record that points to an A record is good practice and helps to ensure you will properly receive and deliver email. Another advantage of having an MX record is that you can specify multiple hosts which can recieve emails with different priorities, and in the event that one host goes down, you can recieve mail at another specified server.

For an example, here's how I have my DNS for mail delivery and sending on my AWS instance.

**`MX` Record for my domain points to mailserver at smtp.roen.us (or mail.example.com):**

`roen.us.                300     IN      MX      1 smtp.roen.us.`

**`A` Record for smtp.roen.us points to mailserver's IP address (or Droplet IP):**

`smtp.roen.us.           300     IN      A       xx.xx.xx.xx`

To summarize, when someone wants to deliver mail to you, they will first look for your MX record, which specifies which hosts are able to receive mail for your domain. 
The person who wants to send you mail will then resolve the MX record to an IP address using the A record, and will establish a connection with your mailserver to deliver the email.